# PL/SQL: Difference between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I've written a procedure to find the difference between two dates and display the result in `YYYY-MM-DD` format but encountered an error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATECALCULATOR(DATE_1 IN DATE, DATE_2 IN DATE) AS
  DATEDIFF DATE;

BEGIN
    DATEDIFF=TO_DATE(DATE_1,'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_DATE(DATE_2,'YYYY-MM-DD');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Date difference is: ' || TO_DATE(DATEDIFF,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
END;
/
```

Excecute procedure code:

```
EXECUTE DATECALCULATOR('2017-09-10', '2010-01-01');
```

Comment: You can't do that. What do you expect as result from your example? `0007-09-10`? Would you consider leap years in this output? What do you consider as "one month" 30 days? 31 days? What is "one year"?

Comment: Thank you!
And what should be done to get the result YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: Was my comment not clear? YYYY-MM-DD is a **DATE**, i.e. a certain point on a time line, resp day in a calendar. The difference between two dates is an interval. You cannot format it as YYYY-MM-DD - at least not in a useful manner. Provide answer to my questions, then you may get solution for an ugly workaround.

Comment: Copied.

Thank you,

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `YYYY-MM-DD` is not a date it is just a formatted string. Given two dates then the difference between them is a number of full calendar months and the remainder is the number of days (and hours, minutes and seconds) - this is easy to find using the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function and some modulo arithmetic (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977827/1509264)). The result represents an interval (and will only make sense in relation to the start date - since moving the start date may cause a different overlap of leap years or months) but it is certainly not a date.

Comment: @MT0, yes `YYYY-MM-DD` is just a formatted string but I did not want to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type to get the format as `+D HH24:MI:SS.FF6`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATECALCULATOR(
  DATE_1 IN DATE,
  DATE_2 IN DATE
) AS
  DATEDIFF INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND;
BEGIN
  DATEDIFF= (DATE_1- DATE_2) DAY(9) TO SECOND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date difference is: ' || DATEDIFF );
END;
/
```

Or, use the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function to get the difference in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATECALCULATOR(
  range_end   IN DATE,
  range_start IN DATE
) AS
  DIFF NUMBER  := TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( DATE_1, DATE_2 ) ) - 1;
  dt   DATE    := ADD_MONTHS( range_start, diff );
  d    INTEGER := TRUNC( range_end - dt );
  dy   INTEGER := EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY( dt ) );
  m    INTEGER;
  y    INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF d > dy THEN
    diff := diff + 1;
    d    := d - dy;
  END IF;
  m := MOD( TRUNC( diff ), 12 );
  y := TRUNC( diff / 12 );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date difference is: '
    || TO_CHAR( y, '0009' ) || '-' || TO_CHAR( m, 'FM09' ) || '-' || TO_CHAR( d, 'FM09' ) 
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried to execute the procedure with the following statement

EXEC DATECALCULATOR('2017-09-10', '2010-01-01');

but i get an error, 

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: `'2017-09-10'` is not a date literal - it is a string literal. Oracle will implicitly try to cast it to a date literal using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask but if that does not match your `YYYY-MM-DD` date format then it will fail. Just use date literals: `EXEC DATECALCULATOR( DATE '2017-09-10', DATE '2010-01-01')`

Comment: Note, the result can be ambiguous. Try `DATECALCULATOR(DATE '2018-08-31', DATE '2018-07-31')` and `DATECALCULATOR(DATE '2018-08-31', DATE '2018-08-01')`. Obviously the time spans are different however, output is `0000-00-30` in either case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I get `0000-01-00` and `0000-00-30` (respectively) for those two pairs.

Comment: Yes, was a mistake. But try `2018-06-30, 2018-05-31` and `2018-06-30, 2018-05-30` or even worse `2018-07-30, 2018-06-30`

Answer (score 3):

If you subtract from one date other you will get a count of days between this two dates. You can't transform this value to date by `to_date` function. And what date you want to get for example difference between dates 456 days it's mean:

`1 year 3 month and several days`

May be better to return formatted string value?

Comment: I want the result in YYYY-MM-DD format. Couldn't get it.

Comment: You can not do that. Look to the comments from @Wernfried Domscheit under the question