# How to find out the exact age of employees as years and months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table with DOB column so, now I want to display all employees current age.
To find out the age I knew the query as below

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ename,
               job,
               dob,
               TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,DOB)/12,1) AGE
        FROM   employee);
```

by using this query I can get all employees age but my requirement is, if a employee age is displayed as 2.5 then I need to display that age as 2 years 6 months.

Comment: You had the total months before you divided by 12.  You just need to find the quotient and remainder when dividing by 12 - in this case 2 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ---

```
SELECT ename,
       job,
       dob, --TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DOB) / 12, 1) AGE
       trunc(months_between(sysdate, DOB) / 12) || ' years ' ||
       trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate, DOB), 12)) || ' months ' AGE
  FROM employee;
```

Comment: Have a look at these comments in order to see why this is not perfect (but most likely sufficient): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974976/pl-sql-difference-between-two-dates/45977827?noredirect=1#comment78917731_45977827

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, yes, the above query is discarding the Days part of the difference. If we need to take that into account then we can modify the query as below ---

Comment: SELECT dob, --TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DOB) / 12, 1) AGE
         trunc(months_between(sysdate, DOB) / 12) || ' years ' ||
         trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate, DOB), 12)) || ' months ' ||
         trunc(sysdate -
               add_months(dob,
                          trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) * 12 +
                          trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate, dob), 12)))) ||
         ' days' AGE
    FROM employee;